# Java app deployment error on azure

Tags: java, deployment, azure, eclipse-plugin

I have written simple hello world Java web app and created package for azure deployment using Eclipse.

While deploying I am getting following error on 40% completion of deployment:

> 12/19/2012 09:40:46 - Configuring Remote Desktop
>   12/19/2012 09:40:50 - Uploading Deployment Package
>   12/19/2012 09:44:58 - Failed uploading deployment package (.cspkg).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you upload the package? Directly from Eclipse, or through portal?

Eclipse tools automatically enable Remote Desktop for all roles. RDP for Azure uses Certificate. The most probable reason for this failure is that the certificate used by default from Eclipse tooling is not uploaded to the Cloud Service. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690951.aspx) to understand more about RDP on Azure and Eclipse.

As for trial I would suggest removing all the following sections from your `.csdef` file:

```
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
```

Also open your `.cscfg` files and remove all the following sections:

```
  <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="C82D51307BCF04EB7401FDBB703FFE517A7F4DD9" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
```

This is just to try uploading clean package. If that works, then check the refered article on how to configure the Remote Desktop Access. The wizard will put appropriate module imports and certificates sections in your files.

Comment: Dear astaykov,

I am also trying to deploy using portal and getting the following status:

Instance status details Waiting for role to start... Application startup tasks are running. [2012-12-20T11:58:37Z]

Comment: And if you wait enough time, doesn't it start?

Comment: Hi Altavista, did you ever get the resolved? I actually have the same issue.